# Configuring a factory inside a service

Tags: angularjs

I have a service `auth` with a function `login`, which logs in to a server and saves an authorization token to a variable:

```
myApp.factory 'auth', ['$http', ($http) ->
    @token = null
    @login = (user, pass) ->

    ...

]
```

After logging in, I update `$http`'s factory to use the defined token in the header of each request.

```
myApp.factory 'httpAuthInterceptor', ($injector, $q) ->
  request: (request) ->
    token = ($injector.get 'auth').token
    request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token
  return request or $q.when request
```

The problem is that the interceptors are configured in the top-level at startup:

```
myApp.config ($httpProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push 'httpAuthInterceptor'
```

How can I reconfigure them after the login function, or as its last step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify the interceptor, once the authentication has completed you should set application wide headers in your auth factory with the below:

`$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token;`